# Contact form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is a pretty basic question, but I'm having difficulty incorporating it in to my application. I've looked at other similar questions on SO, but they all are using the contact page as a separate page.

I have a front-end of a Rails app that is just a small public facing site using stellar.js for parallax scrolling.

At the last part of the page, I would like to have a "Contact Us" form, but I'm getting a

```
NoMethodError in Welcome#index undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Here are the related files:

routes.rb

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
   get "welcome/index"
   root :to => 'welcome#index'
   match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
   match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
```

app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

```
<%= render "contact" %>
```

The partial for the contact section of the page app/views/welcome/_contact.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
     <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name %>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :email %>
        <%= form.text_field :email %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :subject %>
        <%= form.text_field :subject %>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
        <%= form.label :body %>
        <%= form.text_area :body %>
     </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="actions">
     <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

app/controllers/contact_controller.rb

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @message = Message.new
   end

   def create
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])

      if @message.valid?
         NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
         redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
      else
         flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
         render :new
      end
   end
end
```

message.rb

```
class Message

   include ActiveModel::Validations
   include ActiveModel::Conversion
   extend ActiveModel::Naming

   attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

   validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
   validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

   def initialize(attributes = {})
     attributes.each do |name, value|
         send("#{name}=", value)
     end 
   end

   def persisted?
      false
   end
end
```

The question is what do I need to do to make this form to function correctly in the welcome#index view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `@message = Message.new` defined in every action that needs `@message` to be present.

So that means you need this in `WelcomeController`:

```
def index
  @message = Message.new
end
```

A shortcut is to just add it to the top of the partial in case it's not set:

```
<% @message ||= Message.new %>
```

(But you need to decide if mixing in calls to the model within your views is your style. Some devs don't have a problem with this, and some do.)

Comment: Thanks Chris, that worked out great! However, when I click the submit button, nothing happens. It works as expected if I create another view, `app/views/contact/new.html.erb` and put the code from the partial in it and then go to: localhost:3000/contact. Do you happen to have an idea what might cause that? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens?" Are you getting a blank screen or a screen with the form again?

Comment: When I click the submit button, it just sits on the same page. The message is not sent, no blank screen, nothing.

Comment: Would it be something to do with `:url => contact_path` in the partial?

Comment: One possibility is that it's not `POST`ing the data and is grabbing the wrong route. I would think Simple Form would post by default though. Does it say `POST /contact` or `GET /contact` in the console when you submit the form?

Comment: If I add `show Javascript warnings` in the Firebug console, I do receive a warning `Empty string passed to getElementById()`, but nothing else.

Comment: It appears that the problem is with including bootstrap. When I add `   <%= javascript_include_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" %>`, the contact form doesn't work, but when I take it out it works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

You can change following things:

In routes:

Remove:

```
match 'contact' => 'contact#new', :as => 'contact', :via => :get
match 'contact' => 'contact#create', :as => 'contact', :via => :post
```

Add:

```
resources :contact   # It will add 7 default REST routes and standard practice model name should be plural if you created your model with singular then keep it singular
```

In `_contact.html.erb` partial `form path` needs to be `new_contact_path`

```
<%= form_for Message.new, :url => contact_path do |form| %>
```

class `Message` should inherit `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

In `create` action else part should be:

```
if @message.valid?
     NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
     redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
else
     flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
     render :template => "welcome/index"
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question/problem.

Comment: He uses [ActiveModel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model?view=asciicast) technique , the contact form does not need db storage .